# Moving Exports and Column visibility buttons to top CRUD 3.6.28

Tags: laravel-backpack

i'm using Backpack for Laravel and i'm having trouble with export and ColVis buttons.

in my crudcontroller i'm activating the export button 
`$this->crud->enableExportButtons();`

The button are located under the table... it is not convinient.
Is there a way to move them on top of the table near other button, or near filter's buttons ? 
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I think you can publish `resources/views/crud/list.blade.php` and move

```
<div id="datatable_export_stack" class="col-md-6 d-none d-sm-block"></div>
```

wherever you want show export buttons.